# How to make a note using voce command

Tags: voice-command, notes, google-keep

I would like to make a quick note using voice command.
Something like: "OK Google" ..."make a note" ..followed by the message itself.
Preferably using Google Keep but I am open to suggestions.
What the voice command might be?

I tried several variants of make/take note, or just note, all recognized correctly as far as individual words go, but usually ending in launching Chrome web search or in giving me selection of application to handle note, where "Keep" is one of them. But even after selecting Keep, which is not persisted by the way, it is still not very straightforward to actually dictate the note. There must be a better way.

Comment: See [this](https://support.google.com/keep/answer/6356960). It works fairly well , last step is important. I am not into dictating notes but it worked. Oreo 8.0

Comment: Thanks, that helped. _You might need to say "Ok Google" again before you say your note_ ..that did the trick. Hard to guess..

Comment: Interestingly, now it goes straight to Keep, no choice given. It goes straight into taking note after I say "take a note". Nice. Now I face another annoying fact - it also saves audio recording alongside the text. I want just the text, it's usually correct.

Comment: That's a feature of Google Keep. Not possible to delete that AFAIK